# Dependency Injection not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I have been learning MVVM / WPF and have gone through the tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

I have created a working application using this methodology but now, on a new project, I cannot get the Dependency Injection to work.

When I run this project I get an empty MainWindow without the CompanyView injected.  I have double and tripled checked everything between the project that works and this one that doesn't and cannot find the reason for CompanyView not being injected.  I have also tried cleaning the solution and restarting VS to no avail.  Hopefully someone can see what I am missing.

I have the following file:

**App.xaml.cs** (using base.OnStartup() instead of StartupUri in App.xaml)

```
namespace SidekickAdmin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
            window.DataContext = viewModel;
            window.Show();
        }

    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
namespace SidekickAdmin.ViewModel
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            CompanyViewModel companyViewModel = new CompanyViewModel(_repository);
            this.ViewModels.Add(companyViewModel);

        }

        ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> _viewModels;
        ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> ViewModels
        {
            get
            {
                if (_viewModels == null)
                {
                    _viewModels = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
                }
                return _viewModels;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowView.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="SidekickAdmin.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SidekickAdmin.ViewModel"
        xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:SidekickAdmin.View"
        Title="Sidekick Admin" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <!-- Typically done in a resources dictionary -->
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MainWindowResources.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>


    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel}" Margin="3" /> 
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**MainWindowResources.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SidekickAdmin.ViewModel"
                    xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:SidekickAdmin.View">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CompanyViewModel}">
        <vw:CompanyView />
    </DataTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**CompanyViewModel.cs**  (not really used yet as I am still trying to just get the view to appear)

```
namespace SidekickAdmin.ViewModel
{

    class CompanyViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        readonly GenericRepository _repository;

        #region Getters & Setters
        public ObservableCollection<Company> AllCompanies
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public CompanyViewModel(GenericRepository repository)
        {

            if (repository == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
            }

            _repository = repository;

            this.AllCompanies = new ObservableCollection<Company>(_repository.GetAll<Company>());
        }

        #endregion


        protected override void OnDispose()
        {
            this.AllCompanies.Clear();
        }

    }
}
```

**CompanyView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SidekickAdmin.View.CompanyView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="300" Width="300">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>You say Hello</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>And I say Goodbye</TextBlock>    
        <TextBlock>Hello, Hello</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

 </UserControl>
```

Comment: I noticed you have the line `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel}" Margin="3" />`. Shouldn't it be ViewModels with an 's'?

Comment: I don't see where _repository is being created...

Comment: Lester: I corrected this but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Rick: I took out most of that code until I get the view to show with the simple textblocks

Comment: @BrianKE You should edit your code here to reflect this change.

Comment: @BrianKE, ignore my answer from the bottom, i thought you were doing Silverlight. Anyway the error you are making is that your `ViewModels`property is private, make it public it should work then.

Comment: @dmusial Nice catch. This is why I never omit modifiers in my classes - this way it's easier to notice. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Lester should i add another answer or edit the wrong one? still quite new here...

Comment: @dmusial Just add a new answer - I see you've already deleted your previous one.

Comment: you return one observable collection but it is readonly change to ienumerable.

Comment: @Carlos Cocom `ObservableCollection` is not readonly, and what do you mean by changing to `IEnumerable`? He still needs to use some concrete collection type, and by not using `ObservableCollection` he would have to manually notify view about changes in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides what @Robert Levy has wrote, the error you are making is that your `ViewModels` property is private, make it public and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 4):

Lester's comment is right... you are binding to a `ViewModel` property which does not exist - `MainWindowViewModel` has a `ViewModels` property though.  The s is important

Answer (score 1):

@RobertLevy and @dmusial are correct. You need to make your reference to ViewModels in your XAML plural, to match the property name in your C# code. Also, the property should be public, so the View can see it.